# Why does (new Foo())->baa() work but new Foo()->baa() didn't?

Tags: c++, operators

Why does `(new Foo())->baa()` work but `new Foo()->baa()` didn't? Does it has to do with `->` precedence or something like this? I don't know the right term to call this, I'm new to C++...

Comment: Because `Foo` needs a hug before it will do anything even remotely productive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence). `()` and `->` have higher precedence than `new`, so the second expression is treated as if you'd written:

```
new ( ( (Foo() -> baa)() ) )
```